# Swift 3 upload video to Facebook with caption

Tags: swift, facebook, video, upload, caption

The following code is used to upload video to Facebook.  But, how can I supply text/caption/comments associated with the video.  Thanks in advance.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    let video : FBSDKShareVideo = FBSDKShareVideo()
    video.videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL
    let content : FBSDKShareVideoContent = FBSDKShareVideoContent()
    content.video = video
```

}